# how to get the value from request.get in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, httprequest

Below is my code which make http request to a web server having host **78.154.17.70**, port **8080** and path **/csrftoken.json**.

I use `request.get` to get the data from the server. I am able to fetch the data, which is `Json data` in the following format:

```
 {
 "apiVersion": "1.0",
 "data": {
       "csrf": "ajbgajbgjabbjbjbab"
  }
}
```

I declared two variables `var CSRFTokenValue;` and `var respJson;` globally. Inside `request.get`, I use these variables as: `respJson` store the parse data and `CSRFTokenValue` store the

> "csrf": "ajbgajbgjabbjbjbab" token value as "ajbgajbgjabbjbjbab"

means `CSRFTokenValue` will store "ajbgajbgjabbjbjbab" in it.

Now when i log `CSRFTokenValue` inside the `request.get` it will give me the "ajbgajbgjabbjbjbab" but when I log it outside it will give me **undefined** .

I need `CSRFTokenValue` to use in the quesryString inside the `request.post` to post the data.

I don't know how to get the tokenValue globally??

```
var request = require('request');

var CSRFTokenValue;
var respJson;
request.get('http://78.154.17.70:8080/csrftoken.json', function (e, res, body){
    respJson = JSON.parse(body);
    CSRFTokenValue = respJson.data.csrf;
    console.log('GET success:' + CSRFTokenValue);
});

console.log('GET token Globaly:' + CSRFTokenValue);

request.post('http://78.154.17.70:8080/Login/post.json?_csrf=' + CSRFTokenValue, {
    'name' : 'name',
    'password' : 'pass'
}, function (res) {
    console.log('success');
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because when you make your initial request it is being done asynchronously. The program moves right to the next statement in your control flow while your request is done in the background. When the request finishes, `CSRFTokenValue` will be set but you're printing out the value before the request has finished so it's `undefined`.

Try this instead.

```
var request = require('request');

request.get('http://78.154.17.70:8080/csrftoken.json', function (e, res, body){
    var respJson = JSON.parse(body);
    var CSRFTokenValue = respJson.data.csrf;
    console.log('GET success:' + CSRFTokenValue);

    request.post('http://78.154.17.70:8080/Login/post.json?_csrf=' +     CSRFTokenValue, {
        'name' : 'name',
        'password' : 'pass'
    }, function (res) {
        console.log('success');
    });
});
```

This will make your second request once you've gotten the token needed from your first one.

Also, take a look into [asynchronous programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_I/O).

Comment: thanks Rocky for your answer, but when i use **console.log('Status: ' + res.statusCode);** it gives error 'Cannot read property 'statusCode' of null'

Comment: Where are you running that?

Comment: i am running it in terminal.    

   request.post('http://78.154.17.70:8080/Login/post.json?_csrf=' +     CSRFTokenValue, {
        'name' : 'name',
        'password' : 'pass'
    }, function (res) {
console.log('Status: ' + res.statusCode); 
        console.log('success');
    });

Comment: You need to change your function signature to include three arguments.  Try using error, response, and body in that specific order.

Comment: Now, it gives me 403:

Comment: That's correct. There's nothing wrong with your code. Your attempt to login probably failed because 403 is an Forbidden HTTP response code.

Comment: Thank you so much Rocky, its give me forbidden when i log the `body`

Answer (score 0):

The line, 
`console.log('GET token Globaly:' + CSRFTokenValue);`, would execute immediately, bypassing your asynchronous call, `request.get('http://78.154.17.70:8080/csrftoken.json'...`. That's the reason CSRFTokenValue is undefined, as in the declaration, you did not initiate it with a value.

Use a promise to run your `request.post('http://78.154.17.70:8080/Login/post.json?_csrf='...`. Simply run that within request.get when the AJAX call is successful.

Comment: Thanks BikoMT for the quick response but i didn't get it

Comment: I edited my answer. Hopefully that cleared things up. If not, please check this: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/. Hope that helps.